# ReactJS: Is this good way to call siblings method?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am doing this to call siblings method (state) this way:

App.js

```
class App extends Components {
  
  onClick(){
    /*.. calulate total..*/
    this.setState({
      total: window.totalValue
    })
  }
  
  
  render() {
    return (
      <Main>
        {/*..*/}
        <Body onClick={this.onClick}/>
        <Footer total={this.state.total} />
      </Main>
    );
  }
}

class Body extends Components {
  
  onClick(){
    this.props.onClick();
  }
  
  render(){
    return <Section onClick={this.onClick} />
  }
  
}

class Section extends Components{
  
  render(){
    return (
      <button onClick={props.onClick}>Calculate</button>
    )
  }
  
}

class Footer extends Components{
  render(){
    return props.total;
  }
}
```

But its hard to keep passing props to every child components when there are more. Is it okay to do something like this?

Manager.js

```
const Components = {}

export const connect = ( obj ) =>{
  
  Components[obj.constructor.name] = obj;
  return obj;
}

export const manager = () => {
  return Components;
}
```

And in `<Footer/>`'s constructor pass `this` to `connect` function to save its reference:

```
/*...*/
  constructor(props){
   super(props)
   connect(this) // saving component reference to call its method later.
  }
/*...*/
```

And in `<Section/>`, add `onClick` and in `<Footer/>` add `calculateTotal` methods like this:

```
/*.. Section ..*/
  onClick(){
   manager().Footer.calculateTotal();
  }
/*.. Footer ..*/
  calculateTotal(){
    this.setState({
      total: window.totalValue
    })
  }
  
 render(){
    return this.state.total;
  }
```

Later approaches just set the state of `<Footer/>` instead of passing value form `<Main/>` and we don't have to call every `onClick` method (state) when deepest child's state is called.

Thanks in advance for your answer.

Comment: No, that is not a good idea, it actually makes things more complicated because you'll have to keep track of when components are mounted/unmounted, to set the appropriate context to the functions that you call, to update the components' state/props in order for them to be re-rendered, etc.

Comment: If you want you components to have access to the same data, you can use [`Context`](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html). Also, if this is a new app, you should move over to the new way of doing things, using [functional components and hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html).

Comment: Perfect use-case for using React's Context API, which initially solves the issue of "prop drilling".

Comment: @Titus yes this is a new app but I don't understand how I can use hooks or functional components to call siblings method from another child component. Can you share me link to such example and also I don't want to use Context, because reactjs doc says don't use context so often.

Comment: Ideally, you would want to setup your app in such a way that you don't have to call siblings functions. In your example, since you're not using the property passed to `Footer ` to do any calculations, you can use something like `render(){ return this.props.total; }`. The same goes for the `onClick` properties, you can use `onClick={this.props.onClick}` directly.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but my app has something like this: `App>Main>Header|Body|Footer`, `..Main>Body>Section|Aside`, `..Body>Aside>Options` and `Footer` displays `Options` total data. So in order to show calculated data from `Options` in `Footer`, when `Options` states changes, it should call `Footer` state or props to show the latest value. In this case I would have to pass `onClick` from `Main` to `Options` and call `Main`'s `onClick` method from `Options`'s `onClick` to propagate state change from `Main` to `Footer`.

Comment: Do you think there is better way to solve this or my app setup looks poor? To solved this I tried using `Manager.js` function.